# Problems with "Use of unresolved identifier", and "Initializers may only be declared within a type."

Tags: swift, xcode

I am getting "Use of unresolved identifier 'self'" and "Initializers may only be declared within a type" errors in xcode in my Swift code. My code is below and [here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2LIw.png) showing the lines with the errors.
How can I resolve this?

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit.UIImage

class Selfie : Codable
{
    let created : Date
    let id : UUID
}
var title = "New Selfie"
var image : UIImage?
{
     get
{
    return SelfieStore.shared.getImage(id, self.id)
}
     set
{
      try? SelfieStore.shared.setImage(id: self.id, image: newValue)
}
}
init(title: String)
{
     self.title = title
     self.created = Date()
     self.id = UUID()
}
```

Comment: [edit] your question and add tags for `xcode` and `swift` so people can find your question.

Comment: Incorrect curly braces, that’s all.

Comment: I changed the curly braces which helped. But I still have the Use of unresolved identifier error.

Comment: Well, if you are still getting that SelfieStore is an unresolved identifier, that is because it _is_ an unresolved identifier. You sure have not shown _us_ that it is resolved. If you think it is resolved, show us the code that defines it.

Comment: Also why on earth are you importing `UIKit.UIImage`? Just import UIKit and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

In the phrase

```
class Selfie : Codable
{
    let created : Date
    let id : UUID
 }
```

cut the right curly brace and paste it at the end of the whole file.